# HH:MI:SS string to return number of seconds

Tags: regex, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to create a procedure that takes in a string in 'HH:MI:SS' format and RETURN the number of seconds.

I want to parse out the number of hours, minutes and seconds from the string and return the number of seconds for the value passed in.

The procedure is created successfully but when I try calling it I get an error. Can someone please let me know how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONVERT_TO_SECONDS( 
  i_date_string IN VARCHAR2,
    o_seconds      OUT PLS_INTEGER 
)
AS
 l_hours      NUMBER;
 l_minutes  NUMBER;
 l_seconds  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,1)) hours,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,2)) minutes,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,3)) seconds
      INTO l_hours ,
    l_minutes ,
    l_seconds
  FROM dual ;

o_seconds := 
     l_hours*3600 +  
     l_minutes*60 +
     l_seconds;

END;

SELECT CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `select` a ***procedure*** in a SQL statement. You can select a ***function***. Obviously you must create a function, not a procedure - a function that returns integer.

Here is what this may look like. This can still be improved, but I assume this is for practice/learning purposes. (For example, it's not clear why you need to do anything with double-quotes in your code.) I made just the ***fewest*** changes needed to make it work. I will let you find the differences between this and your attempt.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_SECONDS( 
  i_date_string IN VARCHAR2 
)
RETURN INTEGER            
AS
 l_hours      NUMBER;
 l_minutes  NUMBER;
 l_seconds  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,1)) hours,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,2)) minutes,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,3)) seconds
      INTO l_hours ,
    l_minutes ,
    l_seconds
  FROM dual ;
return
     l_hours*3600 +  
     l_minutes*60 +
     l_seconds;
     
END;
/

Function CONVERT_TO_SECONDS compiled
    
SELECT CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08') FROM DUAL;

CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08')
------------------------------
                         29288
```

Comment: thanks for your help and comments. I was struggling with the regexp_substr and found a template so I grabbed it and used it as a template. Now that I have a working example I'll will play around with it to try and make it better

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this with regexes.  Use Oracle's built-in date conversion functions.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('12:34:56','HH24:MI:SS'), 'sssss') FROM dual;
```

Here are some more links with examples:

- https://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2014/10/oracle-convert-time-hhmiss-to-seconds.html
- https://www.complexsql.com/how-to-convert-time-to-seconds-in-oracle-with-examples/
- https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/

Finally, if you tell us "I get an error" then you need to tell us what the error was. Always always always cut & paste the exact error you got. The actual error message is the most important tool for debugging a problem.

Comment: Worth asking the OP (before posting an answer, IMO): "does the procedure, or perhaps function, need to handle *hours* that are more than 24 - for example 35 hours, 30 minutes, 22 seconds"?